# What is .NET recommended practice to interact with MIME-emails with latest Windows OSes?

Tags: .net, parsing, mime

We are using CDO interop (cdont.dll) in our current project for parsing incoming mime mails, but facing some bugs with Cyrillic code pages conversions. While looking for any MS supported replacements, we noticed that all available message parsing dlls marked with "Do not use" in MSDNLib (CDO, CDOex,CDOnt obviously, but inetcomm.dll for "WinXP and later" marked either). Even in recent Windows Mail client inetcomm.dll was used, but MSDN recommend to avoid using it in client apps - "May be removed in future versions".

OK, fine. But what is recommended replacement for parsing messages in MIME formats (all RFCs up to RFC2822)? I saw many open and commercial parsers, but i wonder what is Microsoft's "officially recommended way" to parse MIME messages (I know that .NET FW have mime parser , but all classes marked internal so we can't use it officially) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just little more digging and we found partial solution:

[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Common.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.mime.aspx)

[Mime document:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.mime.mimedocument.aspx)

> This class implements a MIME RFC 2822-compliant parser and holds the resulting 
>   Document Object Model (DOM). The MimeDocument object contains an in-memory 
>   tree representation of a MIME document and enables the
>   navigation and editing of this  document.

Only little problem left - according to this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/87f5502f-53c6-456c-a4d3-78353becef94) and MSFT Member comment it was not officially redistributable (in 2007 =) ).

Anyone know - was it changed since 2007? Need to study some licenses =(.